# Formula automatically changes another field's value

Tags: crystal-reports

My report has 3 database views. My `CountEmployees` formula counts of the number of items in a database view:

```
Count ({BKW_ActiveDirectory.FullName})
```

This worked fine and brought back the expected result. The second formula also works fine:

```
{@CountEmployees} * 40 * 48
```

When I add a third formula to count the amount of records in a *different* database view it changes the value in my first count formula (which in turn changes the second formula.)

```
Count ({BKW_AC_DW_Accident_Incidents.IncidentID})
```

Why is this third formula affecting the other two? They aren't even looking at the same database views. All formulas are placed within the Page Header.

Comment: I believe your first 2 formulas are from same database and when you are using the third formula from different database view there is joining applied on 2 views and resultant result set is forcing first 2 formulas aswell to produce different results. In this case you need to check what kind of linking applied and set the correct linking. If you want to look into the query the remove the 3rd formula then go to label `Database --> Show SQL query` and now add the 3rd formula and check the query. If my assumption is correct then both the queries will be different

Comment: Hi Siva, Thanks for your reply. Yes the formulas are all looking views from the one database but two different tables. The first formula is looking at a view from one table and the 3rd formula is looking at a view from a different table. I tried linking the views together in the Database Export however this causes another issue which makes the first two fields disappear when previewed or printed. Clearing the links solved this issue. I have created sub reports for any additional forumlas but now I am having trouble creating foumulas in the sub reports to calucate fields in other sub reports

Comment: creaqting links won't make tables disapper.. if you can show design I will try to advice what to be done? have observed queries before and after linking